# Count elements of a Dataframe column that meet two conditions

Tags: python, dataframe

`Barcelona_venues` is a pandas data frame that contains two columns (column `Neighborhood` which has the neighborhood values, and column `Venue Category` that has the venue category values). Both contain string values.

I want to know for each neighbourhood in `Barcelona_venues`, the count of number of venues that are contained within the `interesting_venues` list.

I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

---

```
interesting_venues = ["Café", "Bar", "Market", "Pharmacy", "Train Station", "Supermarket", "Convenience Store", "Flower Shop", "Cafeteria", "Metro Station"]

lst = []

Neigh = Barcelona_venues["Neighborhood"].unique()

for i in Neigh:
    
    count = ((Barcelona_venues[Barcelona_venues["Venue Category"] in interesting_venues]) and (Barcelona_venues[Barcelona_venues["Neighborhood"] == i]))
    lst.append[count]

lst
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
interesting_venues = ["Café", "Bar", "Market", "Pharmacy", "Train Station", "Supermarket", "Convenience Store", "Flower Shop", "Cafeteria", "Metro Station"]
lst = []
Neigh = Barcelona_venues["Neighborhood"].unique()

# Loop through each neighborhood
for i in Neigh:
  count = 0
  # Loop through all venue categories for each neighborhood
  for j in Barcelona_venues[Barcelona_venues["Neighborhood"]==i]["Venue Category"]:
    # If it's an interesting category 
    if j in interesting_venues:
      count++
  lst.append[count]
```